# row count on duplicate field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a field in a table that duplicates,
What I would like to do is count this field in a sequence for example the table below

```
ID  TEST
1232
1232
1232
1223
1223
1223
1223
```

I would like to update the filed “TEST” with the following

```
ID  TEST
1232    1   
1232    2
1232    3
1232    4
1224    1
1224    2
1224    3
```

I have been working on this code below but it is not picking out all the duplicates, its just putting most of them as 1.
When I run the code as a select it seems to work fine its just when I run the update part.  Any ideas would be really helpful!!

```
with CTE as (
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [ID] ORDER BY ([ID] ) ) AS Row#,
          [ID] 
   FROM [TABLE]
   WHERE [FIELD2 is not null  and FIELD3 is not null
)
update [TABLE]
set [TEST]= Row# 
from CTE
WHERE [TABLE].FIELD2 is not null 
  and [TABLE].FIELD3 is not null
  and CTE.ROW# = [TABLE].[ID];
```

Comment: The logical issue here is that there is no information in your original table to determine which row number gets assigned to which record in each `ID` partition.

Comment: Your sample data doesnt have Field2 or Field3 but you use it on your query?

Comment: I tagged the question with SQL Server, because you appear to be using that database.

Answer (score 2):

You can just update the CTE directly:

```
with toupdate as (
      SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) seqnum
             t.*
      FROM [TABLE] t
      WHERE FIELD2 is not null  and FIELD3 is not null
     )
update toupdate
    set TEST = seqnum
from CTE;
```

Updatable CTEs are a very nice feature of SQL Server.

I actually prefer `ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)` in the partition clause, because that emphasizes that the ordering is not important.

Answer (score 0):

You need a Primary Key (PK) field on  `YourTable` so you know to what row assign the `Row#` value.

```
with CTE as (
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [ID] ORDER BY [ID] ) AS Row#,
          [ID],
          [table_pk]
   FROM [TABLE]
   WHERE [FIELD2 is not null  and FIELD3 is not null
)
UPDATE [TABLE]
SET [TEST]= Row# 
FROM CTE
WHERE [TABLE].[table_pk] = [CTE].[table_pk];
```

Note you don't need to include the `WHERE` condition again because you are joining only the one you find on the cte already.